# tablet kiosk mode

Tags: android, tablet, kiosk-mode, huawei-mobile-services

I've searched for questions to help me but I have no clear answers.
I need to start an application on my tablet and don't let the user get off from it.
I'm searching something like the "one app method" that I use on my iPad Air 2.
I need it because this tablet goes into a kiosk.

Is it possible to do?
If needed, I can implement some hidden button to get off the kiosk-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Google recently released the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/?utm_source=so&utm_medium=47476535) which allows to easily set up kiosk mode for any Android devices running Android 5.1 or above, and also to set various other policies.

To lock the device on one app, or on multiple app, you define a kiosk policy like below, it will disable the navigation buttons (sample copied from [Create a policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-policy?utm_source=so&utm_medium=46993081#for_devices_running_multiple_apps_from_a_custom_launcher)):

```json
"applications": [
 {
   "packageName": "com.example.app",
   "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
   "lockTaskAllowed": true,
   "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
 },
"persistentPreferredActivities": [
  {
    "receiverActivity": "com.example.app/.com.example.app.MainActivity",
    "actions": [
      "android.intent.action.MAIN"
    ],
    "categories": [
      "android.intent.category.HOME",
      "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
    ]
  }
]
```